# GitLab SSH to server to run docker stack deploy, getting no file found

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, docker-swarm, continuous-deployment

I have a CI/CD pipeline set up with GitLab which is running perfectly, apart from the final deploy stage. When getting a shell in my deployment server and trying to run "docker stack deploy -c deploy-stack.yml reactclient" I am getting "No File Found" for deploy-stack.yml which causes the deployment to fail.

Prior to running this command I am running "ls" which prints out a list of files inside my container, one of which is deploy-stack.yml. However when running this next command deploy-stack.yml is not found?!

This is the deploy stage in my .gitlab-ci.yml which is failing:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - docker:dind
  tags:
    - runner
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://app.mydeployserver.com
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$DEPLOY_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - echo "Start deploy to production server"
    - ssh root@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "
        echo $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP;
        echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY;
        docker pull $IMAGE_TAG;
        echo "Where am I? - $PWD";
        echo "What files are in here? - $(ls)";
        docker stack deploy -c deploy-stack.yml reactclient"
    - echo "End deploy to production server"
```

As you can see right before docker stacker deploy, I am running `echo "What files are in here? - $(ls)` which literally prints out deploy-stack.yml

Yet the job fails due to "No File Found", here is the output from GitLab:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/myusername/myimage:latest
Where am I? - /builds/myusername/myimage
What files are in here? - Dockerfile __mocks__ appspec.yml build config deploy-stack.yml jest.config.js local.Dockerfile nginx package-lock.json package.json scripts server src webpack.dev.js webpack.prod.config.js webpack.prod.js
open deploy-stack.yml: no such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Where am I going wrong? Is this something to do with the command being run by some other docker daemon? This gets really confusing with gitlab + docker vs dind + ssh to another server.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: strange issue, did you try to put absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this part of your code:

```
    - ssh root@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "
        echo $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP;
        echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY;
        docker pull $IMAGE_TAG;
        echo "Where am I? - $PWD";
        echo "What files are in here? - $(ls)";
        docker stack deploy -c deploy-stack.yml reactclient"
```

You open the quotes `- ssh root@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "` and you close them on the line `echo "Where am I? - $PWD";`.

You could try the following:

```
    - ssh root@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "
        echo $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP;
        echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY;
        docker pull $IMAGE_TAG;
        echo Where am I? - $PWD;
        echo What files are in here? - $(ls);
        docker stack deploy -c deploy-stack.yml reactclient"
```